# Function containing exactly one of each of the 5 vowels

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a function to evaluate if contains exactly one of each of the 5 vowels.

I've tried so far: (I don't know how can I limit now for only 1 of each vowel)

```
def isVowel(char): #=> Helper function
    return len(char) == 1 and char.lower() in 'aeiou'

def fiveVowelsOneOfEach(word):
    oneVowelOfEachCounter = 0
    for char in word:
        if isVowel(char):
            if char == 'a':
                oneVowelOfEachCounter += 1
            if char == 'e':
                oneVowelOfEachCounter += 1
            if char == 'i':
                oneVowelOfEachCounter += 1
            if char == 'o':
                oneVowelOfEachCounter += 1
            if char == 'u':
                oneVowelOfEachCounter += 1
            if oneVowelOfEachCounter == 5: 
                return True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
s = 'aeiou'
s2 = 'aaeiou'
def checker(s):
    return all(s.lower().count(i)==1 for i in 'aeiou')
print(checker(s))
print(checker(s2))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

That's all needed, checking if the counts of each vowel is one

Comment: Wow, I really liked this solution maybe I was just a little overthinking. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of doing it

```
goodstr = 'aeiou'
badstr = 'aaeiou'
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'] # or a string "aeiou"

def fiveVowelsIsOneOfEach(word):
    for vowel in vowels:
        if word.count(vowel) != 1:
            return False
    return True


print(fiveVowelsIsOneOfEach(goodstr))   # returns True
print(fiveVowelsIsOneOfEach(badstr))    # returns False
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It works if not contains exactly 5 vowels.. For example goodstr= 'aeio' returns True

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to address the issues in the question. Also added a version that does not use counter.

```
from collections import Counter

word = 'aaeiuo'
vowels = 'aeiuo'
c = Counter(word)
vowel_count = sum([1 if c[vowel] > 0 else 0 for vowel in vowels])
print(vowel_count) # 5
#without using counter
vowel_count = sum([1 if word.count(vowel) > 0 else 0 for vowel in vowels])
print(vowel_count) # 5
```

Comment: So how do you know that each vowel appeared once? Maybe the string had five `a`s and 0 other vowels.

Comment: Also , I'm not allowed to import modules.
I only can rely in iterations

Comment: Well.. Aran-Fey is completely right, note should add if to check, (even tho doesn't work)

Comment: Problem is what happens if you have 5 `'a'`s and no other vowels that still says `5` right?, that's nor right then, has to be all vowels in string and they all count to `1`

Comment: addressed the issues in comments and rewrote the code. Shouldn't post answers in a rush ..

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Ok, good, i didn't downvote so no way to undownvote...

Answer (score 0):

```
def fiveVowelsOneOfEach(word):
    oneVowelOfEachCounter = 0
    vowels = list('aeiou')
    dummy_vowels = list(chars)
    for char in word:
        if char in vowels:
            vowels.remove(char)
            continue
        elif char in dummy_vowels:
            return False
    if len(vowels) == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

This should work. the trick is to use a list and a dummy list to make sure each vowel is only counted once.

Comment: Hello, I've tried this way but did not work, but thank you for the feedback